# How do I get tuples of primary keys of models related to each other using the django orm?

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

Assuming I have four models, where two models define types and two models are instances of these types, which have a 1-to-n relationship:

```
class SuperTypeA(Model):
    pass

class InstanceofA(Model):
    definition = ForeignKey(SuperTypeA, null=False)

class SubTypeB(Model):
    supertype = ForeignKey(SuperTypeA, null=False)

class InstanceofB(Model):
    definition = ForeignKey(SubTypeB, null=False)
    related = ForeignKey(InstanceofA, null=False)
```

In plain English, a SuperTypeA has n SubTypeB, and n InstanceofA. A SubTypeB has n InstanceofB. A InstanceofA has n InstanceofB.

I would like to get the tuples of the primary keys of SuperTypeA, SubTypeB, InstanceofB given some constraints on InstanceofA. In SQL:

```
SELECT SuperTypeA.id, SubTypeB.id, InstanceofB.id 
FROM SuperTypeA, SubTypeB, InstanceofB, InstanceofA
WHERE InstanceofA.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How do I do that using the Django ORM, without using raw queries?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this: `InstanceofB.objects.all().values_list('definition', 'related')`

You can change the `all` method for the `filter` one if you want to set some kind of condition.